# Bar plot using ggplot without NA values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this data set:

```
structure(list(sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Male", 
"Female"), class = "factor"), ph006d1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("238834", "140684", 
"313895", "357343", "395260", "113302", "261429", "56770", "246735", 
"44335", "243570", "291491", "169951", "84282", "128746", "370073", 
"184552", "142856", "159969", "222004", "214571", "206412", "9604", 
"408052", "247889", "160392", "112151", "294933", "60628", "255761", 
"183798", "355557", "382694", "179322", "232143", "8384", "64595", 
"130937", "58238", "211288", "89741", "274124", "15498", "263105", 
"16023", "294046", "158389", "194203", "249063", "263042", "269633", 
"273931", "334222", "307707", "143820", "394474", "170366", "77730", 
"263558", "215557", "108658", "280293", "153393", "19683", "76186", 
"398330", "291272", "381430", "7460", "5354", "319521", "132904", 
"222158", "34189", "403611", "206023", "37337", "70288", "371791", 
"46469", "307796", "196647", "145693", "181532", "152799", "298512", 
"325908", "410652", "315940", "224851", "109837", "339716", "94379", 
"85190", "92170", "308636", "332581", "344942", "15515", "406412"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to perform a barplot using ggplot()

If I use this code:

```
ggplot(datasample,aes(x=ph006d1))+geom_bar(stat="count")
```

Error: (converted from warning) Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count)

I cannot understand why, I require to count the values of 1 and 0 and put in a barplot

Then I used:

```
ggplot(datasample,aes(x=factor(ph006d1)))+geom_bar(stat="count")
```

That worked but with an error

[image]

because in the variable there are no NA values.

In fact

```
table(datasample$ph006d1)
```

gives the result:

```
 0  1 
91  8
```

Why I am getting NA? how to do properly this barplot ??

Comment: There is a missing in your `ph006d1`. See `table(datasample$ph006d1, useNA = "always")`. The message you get with your first trial ins't an error. It's just a warning which informs you that the obs with the missing value was dropped. To silent this warning you could eg. do `geom_bar(na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

One of your observations is missing, So if it is really missing and you want to keep NA in the dataset and produce the bar plot you can filter them using tidyverse package and pass filtered data to ggplot function:

```
library(tidyverse)
filter(datasample, !is.na(ph006d1)) %>%
ggplot(.,aes(x=factor(ph006d1)))+ geom_bar(stat="count")
```

Hope it helps.

[image]